# Django update model without UpdateView

Tags: django

I have a scenario where in my users profile they have an associated organisation. I need to be able to allow the users to select and set this organisation (user_organization), however I would like to do it without allowing them to just see a list (drop down menu) of all the organisations within the application. My work around for this was to issue each organisation with a unique code (org_code) and allow users to enter that code into a form and have the related organisation applied to their profile. I can easily understand the suedocode logic behind this, however I am unsure how to implement it within my views and forms. If anyone can advise me the best way to do this or point me in the correct direction to learn how? It would be appreciated. See my models below for clarification on how things fit together.

Profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    Super_Admin = "Super_Admin"
    Admin = "Admin"
    Manager = "Manager"
    Developer = "Developer"
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (Super_Admin, 'Super_Admin'),
        (Admin, 'Admin'),
        (Manager, 'Manager'),
        (Developer, 'Developer'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_group = models.OneToOneField(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    user_organization = models.OneToOneField(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default="Developer", max_length=12)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Organizations:

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, unique=True)
    org_code = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, unique=True, default=GenerateOrganozationCode)
```

Comment: I dont understand this bit of your question:
"I would like to do it without allowing them to just see a list of all the organisations within the application". If I am reading this correctly, you do NOT want them to select from a drop down list. Can you clarify what you actually want?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity, you are correct in the assumption that I don't want them to be able to select from a drop down. I want them to be able to input a code into a text field which when submitted, if it matches the code (org_code) in the organisation model it will then populate the (user_organization) in their Profile with the correct (org_name). Hopefully this help, its all a little confusing to word correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering using the extra info from the comments you've made above:

"I want them to be able to input a code into a text field which when submitted, if it matches the code (org_code) in the organization model it will then populate the (user_organization) in their Profile with the correct (org_name)"

Within the logic for the view, you need to extract the org_code. You should also make org_code of Organization the primary key of the object (you dont have to, but it would be easier if the pk was the org code). From here, you can map the org_code with the primary key value of Organization.

```
Organization.objects.get(pk=the_entered_org_code)
```

If you'd rather not assign org code as the primary key of the object, you can just filter for the org code.

```
Organization.objects.filter(org_code=the_entered_org_code)
```

This should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, for the help. It wasn't quite what I wanted (my fault for bad question phrasing), however it pointed me in the correct direction to get this working! cheers